Trying to call an already existing form (page)
I am programming a desktop software for my workouts and I have a main form, in which I have a page for "short-term planning" (pg_KurzfristigeTrainingplanung). From that page I call another form (frm_KurzfristigeTrainingsplanung), where I enter the dates and the workouts I want to train those days. With a button I want to "feed back" those entries to that very same page "short-term planning" (pg_KurzfristigeTrainingplanung) from which I called the form for the planning.
The values I entered in the form shall then be entered into the page and also "stay" there until I change them again (as well after closing the entire program).
How can I initiate or tell the program to refer back to that page?
private void btnEintragen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pg_KurzfristigeTrainingsplanung pgKF = pg_KurzfristigeTrainingsplanung;

    // Schleife von 1 bis 7
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            // Spezialfall für i = 1: DateTimePicker und TextBox
            DateTimePicker dtpDatum1 = (DateTimePicker)this.Controls.Find("dtpDatum1", true).FirstOrDefault();
            Label lblDatum1 = (Label)pgKF.Controls.Find("lblDatum1", true).FirstOrDefault();

            if (dtpDatum1 != null)  // && lblDatum1 != null
            {
                lblDatum1.Text = dtpDatum1.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Standardfall für i = 2 bis 7: Labels
            Label lblDatumFormKF = (Label)this.Controls.Find("lblDatum" + i, true).FirstOrDefault();
            Label lblTrainingFormKF = (Label)this.Controls.Find("lblTraining" + i, true).FirstOrDefault();
            Label lblFocusFormKF = (Label)this.Controls.Find("lblFocus" + i, true).FirstOrDefault();

            Label lblDatumpgKF = (Label)pgKF.Controls.Find("lblDatum" + i, true).FirstOrDefault();
            Label lblTrainingpgKF = (Label)pgKF.Controls.Find("lblTraining" + i, true).FirstOrDefault();
            Label lblFocuspgKF = (Label)pgKF.Controls.Find("lblFocus" + i, true).FirstOrDefault();

            // Falls die Controls gefunden wurden, deren Text übertragen
            if (lblDatumFormKF != null && lblDatumpgKF != null)
            {
                lblDatumpgKF.Text = lblDatumFormKF.Text;
            }

            if (lblTrainingFormKF != null && lblTrainingpgKF != null)
            {
                lblTrainingpgKF.Text = lblTrainingFormKF.Text;
            }

            if (lblFocusFormKF != null && lblFocuspgKF != null)
            {
                lblFocuspgKF.Text = lblFocusFormKF.Text;
            }
        }
    }

    //Schliesst die Form nach erfolgreichem Eintragen der Daten
    this.Close();
}

I tried to feed back the values from the "planning-form" back to the earlier page.
I expected the values to show up, but the values did not show up on the page "pg_KurzfristigeTrainingsplanung"

You need to open the child form as modal, then get data from it:
DateTime date1, date2;
var frm = new frm_KurzfristigeTrainingsplanung();
var result = frm.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
    // Assuming a couple of DateTimePicker there.
    date1 = frm.DateTimePicker1.Value;
    date2 = frm.DateTimePicker2.Value;
    // ...
}
frm.Dispose();
// Use date1 and date2 on pg_KurzfristigeTrainingplanung

Here the minimal Forms app which utilizes a child form. On the button click the child form displays to pick a date. Then the main form displays the picked date in a label. Data passes through public members of the child form.
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ProjectTestMyLabel1 {
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 frmMain = new Form1();
            Application.Run(frmMain);
        }
    }
    class Form1 : Form {
        Label _label;
        Button _button;
        public Form1() {
            SuspendLayout();
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(8F, 16F);
            ClientSize = new Size(300, 84);
            Controls.AddRange(
                new Control[] {
                    _label = new Label() {
                        Location = new Point(12, 12),
                        Size = new Size(100, 23),
                    },
                    _button = new Button() {
                        Location = new Point(12, 48),
                        Size = new Size(100, 23),
                        Text = "Date picker"
                    }
                }
            );
            Text = Name = "Form1";
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            ResumeLayout(false);
            _button.Click += _button_Click;
        }
        void _button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var frm = new Form2();
            var result = frm.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
                _label.Text = frm.Dtp.Value.ToString();
            }
            frm.Dispose();
        }
    }
    class Form2 : Form {
        public DateTimePicker Dtp;
        public Form2() {
            SuspendLayout();
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(8F, 16F);
            ClientSize = new Size(300, 84);
            Controls.AddRange(
                new Control[] {
                    Dtp = new DateTimePicker() {
                        Location = new Point(12, 12)
                    },
                    new Button() {
                        Location = new Point(12, 48),
                        Size = new Size(100, 23),
                        Text = "Close",
                        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
                    }
                }
            );
            Text = Name = "Form2";
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }
}

Another way is to pass data utilizing the dedicated variable:
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ProjectTestMyLabel1 {
    class DataTransfer {
        public DateTime[] Dates;
        public string[] Workouts;
        public DataTransfer(int num) {
            Dates = new DateTime[num];
            Workouts = new string[num];
        }
    }
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 frmMain = new Form1();
            Application.Run(frmMain);
        }
    }
    class Form1 : Form {
        Label _labeld, _labelw;
        Button _button;
        public Form1() {
            SuspendLayout();
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(8F, 16F);
            ClientSize = new Size(300, 84);
            Controls.AddRange(
                new Control[] {
                    _labeld = new Label() {
                        Location = new Point(12, 12),
                        Size = new Size(100, 23),
                    },
                    _labelw = new Label() {
                        Location = new Point(124, 12),
                        Size = new Size(100, 23),
                    },
                    _button = new Button() {
                        Location = new Point(12, 48),
                        Size = new Size(100, 23),
                        Text = "Subform"
                    }
                }
            );
            Text = Name = "Form1";
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            ResumeLayout(false);
            _button.Click += _button_Click;
        }
        void _button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            DataTransfer dataTransfer;
            var frm = new Form2(dataTransfer = new DataTransfer(1));
            var result = frm.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
                _labeld.Text = dataTransfer.Dates[0].ToString();
                _labelw.Text = dataTransfer.Workouts[0];
            }
            frm.Dispose();
        }
    }
    class Form2 : Form {
        DataTransfer _dataTransfer;
        DateTimePicker _dtp;
        TextBox _tb;
        public Form2(DataTransfer dataTransfer) {
            SuspendLayout();
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(8F, 16F);
            ClientSize = new Size(300, 84);
            Controls.AddRange(
                new Control[] {
                    _dtp = new DateTimePicker() {
                        Location = new Point(12, 12)
                    },
                    _tb = new TextBox() {
                        Location = new Point(12, 48),
                        Size = new Size(100, 23)
                    },
                    new Button() {
                        Location = new Point(124, 48),
                        Size = new Size(100, 23),
                        Text = "Close",
                        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
                    }
                }
            );
            Text = Name = "Form2";
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            ResumeLayout(false);
            _dataTransfer = dataTransfer;
        }
        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e) {
            _dataTransfer.Dates[0] = _dtp.Value;
            _dataTransfer.Workouts[0] = _tb.Text;
        }
    }
}


Hi rotabor,
thanks for your answer.
How do I call the page on which the data shall be displayed then?
Also via e.g. "var pg=new pg_KurzfristigeTrainingsplanung" and the fiving the variables "pg.lblDate1.Text"=date1?
I get an error thrown then (CS0122 and CS0165)
